# Linear least squares of factorizable 2D polynomial

Tags: least-squares, polynomials, data-fitting

I would like to fit 2D data where my function is a product of two 1D polynomials of 4th order.

```
f(x,y) = (a0 + a1*x + ... + a4*x^4)*(b0 + b1*y ... + b4*y^4)
```

I know that I can solve this using any optimization routine that uses non-linear least squares.
Is there a way to use a linear least square method to fit such a factorizable polynomial?

I could expand the polynomial and formulate the problem as

```
(1, x1, y1, x1*y1, x1^2, y1^2, x1^2*y1, ...) * X = f(x1, y1)
                     .                                 .
                     .                                 .
                     .                                 .
```

and solve for `X = (a0*b0, a1*b0, a0*b1, ...)^T`.

Then I have the problem, that the system of equations that define a0, a1, ... and b0, b1, ... is overdetermined (X has length 5*5 = 25, but I have only 5+5=10 independent variables).

Constrained least squares (using e.g. `L*X = d`) also does not seem to work, since the constraints are non-linear.

Is there any (tricky?) way to use linear least squares for this type of problem?

Comment: If the answer is positive, it must also work for the 1D case, which is much simpler.  Have you tried this? Also, most likely it suffices to consider the quadratic case, to start with.

Comment: @zkoza 1D polyomials can always be fit by linear least squares. The 2D problem for the quadratic case has exactly the same problem, as X has size 3*3=9 for only 3+3=6 coefficients.

Comment: I see, https://mathworld.wolfram.com/LeastSquaresFittingPolynomial.html  Have you tried a similar derivation for your problem? You wold have exactly as many equations as unknowns.

Comment: @zkoza yes, thats exactly what I did. As I said, for 1D this always works, for 2D it works only if you want coefficients of the expanded polynomial (then `X` directly contains the coefficients) and not the factorized.

Comment: b0 or a0 is redundant: the system of equations will always have infinite number of solutions (just as `f(x) = a * b * x + c`). So one of them should be set to a const, for example, 1.

Comment: I think even for linear functions in x & y the problem has no solution. But stackoverflow is not the best place to ask this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/ ?

Comment: @zkoza thanks for pointing this out, indeed I use b0 = 1. I have asked this question now herer :) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4021610/linear-least-squares-of-factorizable-2d-polynomial

Comment: A method of fitting thanks to linear regressions is given in : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4022966